# Application entry and call sequence when .ipa start up

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, ios5

I migrate recently from C programming to iphone development with Xcode. It seems the IDE hides a lot of trivial things and I'm curious about what's going on under the hood.

I find a file named `main.m` in my project. Inside this function, `UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` is invoked. My question is what tasks will the `UIApplicationMain` completes?  Can I step into this function tracking its execution?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Cocoa Touch apps use an event driven paradigm, instead of being strictly sequential procedural code.

UIApplicationMain() tells the OS and Objective C runtime to set things up (plist'ed defaults, main nib, run loop, etc.) and then have the main run loop start dispatching to methods within your app.  Put breakpoints at the beginning of all your (init/load/event handling) methods to see what the OS starts calling first.

The OS does a whole bunch of things you can't step into.  You have to wait until it's good and ready to call methods within your app.

Comment: Then any advice on ipa debugging? I'm nearly driven to crazy, quite different from C programming.:)

Comment: Lots of breakpoints until you figure out the order things (delegate methods mostly) get called.  Maybe lots of NSLogs in Debug builds.

Answer (score 1):

`UIApplicationMain` is the entry point for the Cocoa app. It sets up the app's primary application class and its delegate, and starts running the event loop. It doesn't return.

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html):

> This function instantiates the application object from the principal
>   class and and instantiates the delegate (if any) from the given class
>   and sets the delegate for the application. It also sets up the main
>   event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins
>   processing events. If the application’s Info.plist file specifies a
>   main nib file to be loaded, by including the NSMainNibFile key and a
>   valid nib file name for the value, this function loads that nib file.

You don't really want to step into the guts of that specific function, because there's just a whole stew of binary instructions to look at that won't be enlightening. But the way to think of it, is that it's the "container" function for your whole app. Once it does its setup work, it starts event processing in an run loop, and will call out into your code when appropriate. It will be at the bottom of the callstack for all your app's code on the main thread.

Check out the great diagrams on this page for more about an app's lifecycle, which should give you some hints about where to put breakpoints in your own code, and how they will be called:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/ApplicationLifeCycle.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. :)